# Empty tag content with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the following HTML webpage :

http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1/results/

in order to extract the data inside the tag "div id=tournamentTable" located here :

```
body > div class="wrap" > div id="mother-main" > div id="mother > div id="wrap" > div id="box-top" > div id="box-bottom" > div id="main" > div id="col-left" > div id="col-content" > div id="tournamentTable"
```

However when I run the following code :

```
f=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1/results/") 
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find_all("div",id="tournamentTable")
```

I get nothing inside the tag div id="tournamentTable". I can't get the data inside the Table : class="table-main".

Let me know if you have a solution.

Thanks !

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically by the browser using JavaScript, rather than being directly in the initial source HTML. Use selenium.

Comment: Expanding on what Alex said, if you go to that page and hit Ctrl-U to view source, you'll see that there isn't anything in that div in the html itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-sport-country-tournament-archive/1/OO2KUIR8/X0/1/0/2/?_=1479516929965

you can find you data in this link, it uses javascript to fetch date, you should try selenium!